# c# - get local dropbox synchronisation status

Tags: c#, synchronization, local, dropbox, status

I was wondering what would be the best way in c# to get information about the synchronization status of a local dropbox instance. Unfortunately i found no info in the registry or any logfile. Suggestions or snippets are welcomed.
Four status would be enough: Synced, Syncing, Paused, Error.

Br, Matthias.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a Delphi port of an old Python script flying around. It uses the Win32 API with a Named Pipe to query the dropbox application about the file status. You should be able to port this over to C# with no hassle:

https://bitbucket.org/h4ndy/dropboxdelphi/src

You get the following states from it: 'Pipe Error', 'Dropbox not running', 'Not in Dropbox', 'Up to Date', 'Sync in Progress', 'Sync Problem'

Comment: Do you have a link to the old python script ?

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue: http://web.archive.org/web/20100217082257/http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/PythonScriptToGetFileOrFolderStatusInWindows

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but have you checked the Addons page of the DropBox wiki?  http://dropboxwiki.com/Dropbox_Addons  This got me the same info for Linux systems, so hopefully will help you out too.